# How can I delete Navigation Links from the Quick Launch in SP2010?

Tags: 2010, navigation, quick-launch

We have added Navigation Links to other sites in the Quick Launch menu but would like to delete them because they are not longer required, how can we get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site Actions, Site Settings, Quick Launch (or Navigation if you have the publishing infrastructure) in the Look and Feel section.  Find the desired items, delete them and you're all set.  Steps vary slightly if you have the Quick Launch option vs Navigation.

Comment: I realised that you have to click on the icon for the item you want to delete, there is no check box or other option visible. Thanks for your help.